# How to retrieve data from two tables in Parse?

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform

I have a "post" table and "user" table in Parse. I am querying the "post" table in my application but I also wish to obtain data from the "user" table about the user that posted the post. Normally I would do a sub query but I can't figure out how to do that when I need to know the user objectID before the query starts that was used to post. How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: Does the "Post" table include a pointer to the user object?  If so you can use `includeKeys("userPointerFieldName")` to retrieve the user object at the same time

Comment: I've tried that "<PFUser: 0x7faa73d1dfc0, objectId: ThAOChCCRq, localId: (null)>" that is what i get in return. I don't see how to return the data in the table associated with that object id without another query. Is there a way?

Comment: So that is your PFUser object - simply access its properties